# Why is my android app crashing on start up

Tags: java, android, android-activity, methods

I am just starting to learn about making android apps and I am trying this speech recognition app on my android studio. When I hit RUN, the emulator Api 29 opens up, shows a blank page and then closed with the a CLOSE APP! window. It does the same thing on my android phone Api 24.

I went through all possible causes on your related past members problems but I found no similar solution.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

         private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO = 1;   // MIC PERMISSION VARIABLE
        // private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_PERMISSION = 1;

          android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech TTS;   //variable del TextToSpeech
          SpeechRecognizer speechRecog;

         private android.widget.ProgressBar progressBar;
         private SpeechRecognizer speech = null;
         private android.content.Intent recognizerIntent;
         private String LOG_TAG = "VoiceRecognitionActivity";



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //android.widget.TextView returnedText = (findViewById(R.id.textView1));
        progressBar = (findViewById(R.id.progressBar1));
        android.widget.ToggleButton toggleButton = (findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1));
        progressBar.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);


        final SpeechRecognizer speech = SpeechRecognizer
                .createSpeechRecognizer(MainActivity.this);


        android.util.Log.i(LOG_TAG, "isRecognitionAvailable: " + SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this));

        speech.setRecognitionListener((android.speech.RecognitionListener) this);
        recognizerIntent = new android.content.Intent(android.speech.RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(android.speech.RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,  "en");

        recognizerIntent.putExtra(android.speech.RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                android.speech.RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(android.speech.RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);

        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


            public void onCheckedChanged(android.widget.CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

                } else {


                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
                    speech.stopListening();
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is a copy of the LOGCAT

```
2019-07-11 14:58:46.703 32610-32610/com.example.speech_recognition E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.speech_recognition, PID: 32610
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.speech_recognition/com.example.speech_recognition.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.speech_recognition.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.speech.RecognitionListener
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.speech_recognition.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.speech.RecognitionListener
        at com.example.speech_recognition.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7783)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7772)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934) 
2019-07-11 14:58:46.739 32610-32610/com.example.speech_recognition I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32610 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The log says the error is on line 51. Could you highlight that one: `Caused by:... at com.example.speech_recognition.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51) `

Comment: this is line 51:
 speech.setRecognitionListener((android.speech.RecognitionListener) this);   then,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is failing in this line:

```
speech.setRecognitionListener((android.speech.RecognitionListener) this);
```

The problem is your `MainActivity` does not implement the interface [`RecognitionListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html) and so it cannot be cast to that type.

Comment: Thanks David for answering my question.
the line you just pointed out was already on my program. I missed it when I made the copy-paste.
Sorry for this.

David, I went ahead and run the debugger on my android studio and I found out that the program is blocking
at this line   

 speech.setRecognitionListener((android.speech.RecognitionListener) this);   then,

it shows me this warning:
Decompiled .class file, bytecode version 52.0 (Java 8)
Sources for 'Android API 29 Platform' not found.

I verified the android SDK list and I do have Android 9.+(Q) installed.

Comment: @AndresVasquez MainActivity is not a RecognitionListener. If you don't implement RecognitionListener or extend some class that does, you will not be able to cast it to a RecognitionListener. On the other hand, if you do implement that interface, there would be no need for the cast.

Comment: Thanks. I got it !